# accessing ram file from /mnt path in apache

Tags: php, apache

I have created a `ram file` in the directory `/mnt/tempram/temp1`
I have used commands:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/tempram
mount -t ramfs -o size=128K ramfs /mnt/tempram
```

Now i have created a php file to download this file

```
<?php
$file = "/mnt/tempram/temp1";
if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

I am unable to access this file. I understand this problem with the apache web server.
Kindly help!!

Comment: What error do you get? It is possible for you to add relevant parts of your `httpd.conf` to the question?

Comment: Hint: You could also access the RAM without doing a mount operation by simply using [the `php://memory` stream wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#refsect2-wrappers.php-unknown-unknown-unknown-unknown-unknown-descriptios) with some file function (e.g. `fopen`).